# If $ab+bc+ca=3$ for non-negative $a$, $b$, $c$, show that $\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+\sum_{cyc}\frac{12a^2b^2c^2}{(a+b)^2}\ge 12abc$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

**Problem**

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0$,and such $ab+bc+ca=3$, show that
>   $$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{12a^2b^2c^2}{(a+b)^2}\ge 12abc\tag{1}$$

A few hours ago, I asked for an error inequality.

**Wrong inequality**:Let $a,b,c\ge 0$,and such $ab+bc+ca=3$, show that
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{12a^2b^2c^2}{(a+b)^2}\ge 12$$

Now,I think inequality $(1)$ is right,I want use well know Iran 96 inequality 
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{(a+b)^2}\ge\dfrac{9}{4(ab+bc+ac)}=\dfrac{3}{4}$$It suffices to  prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+9a^2b^2c^2\ge 12abc?$$

Comment: The last inequality you wrote unfortunately does not hold.  Try for e.g. $a=3, b=c = 2\sqrt3-3$.  So you need something tighter.

Answer (score 3):

Since for $abc=0$ our inequality is obvious, we can assume that $abc\neq0.$

Let $bc=x$, $ac=y$ and $ab=z$.

Thus, $x+y+z=3$, $a=\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x}}$, $b=\sqrt{\frac{xz}{y}},$ $c=\sqrt{\frac{xy}{z}}$ and we need to prove that
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+12xyz\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{xz}{y}}\right)^2}\geq4\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^2+\frac{12x^2y^2}{(x+y)^2}\right)\geq4\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2-xy)+4(xy+xz+yz)-4\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}\geq3\sum_{cyc}\left(xy-\frac{4x^2y^2}{(x+y)^2}\right)$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2+\frac{2\sum\limits_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2}{xy+xz+yz+\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}}\geq3\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy(x-y)^2}{(x+y)^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{xy+xz+yz+\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}}-\frac{6xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)\geq0$$ and since $xy+xz+yz\geq\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)},$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{2z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)\geq0.$$ 
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$1+\frac{2x^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6yz}{(y+z)^2}\geq1+\frac{2x^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6yz}{4yz}=\frac{4x^2-xy-xz-yz}{2(xy+xz+yz)}\geq0.$$
Also, by AM-GM again we have
$$1+\frac{2y^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xz}{(x+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{2(x+z)^2y^2+(x^3-3x^2z-3xz^2+z^3)y+xz(x^2-4xz+z^2)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{y(2(x+z)^2y+x^3-3x^2z-3xz^2+z^3)+xz(x^2-4xz+z^2)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{y(2(x+z)^2z+x^3-3x^2z-3xz^2+z^3)+xz(x^2-4xz+z^2)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{y(x^3-x^2z+xz^2+3z^3)+xz(x^2-4xz+z^2)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{z(x^3-x^2z+xz^2+3z^3)+xz(x^2-4xz+z^2)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{z(2x^3-5x^2z+2xz^2+3z^3)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}=\frac{z\left(3\cdot\frac{2}{3}x^3+2xz^2+6\cdot\frac{1}{2}z^3-5x^2z\right)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{x^2z^2\left(10\sqrt[10]{2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6}-5\right)}{(xy+xz+yz)(x+z)^2}\geq0.$$
Id est,
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{2z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-z)^2\left(1+\frac{2y^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xz}{(x+z)^2}\right)+(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{2z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{2y^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xz}{(x+z)^2}\right)+(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{2z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{6xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)=$$
$$=2(x-y)^2\left(1+\frac{y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{3xz}{(x+z)^2}-\frac{3xy}{(x+y)^2}\right)$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$1+\frac{y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}-\frac{3xz}{(x+z)^2}-\frac{3xy}{(x+y)^2}\geq0$$ or
$$(y+z)x^5-yzx^4+3(y^3-2y^2z-2yz^2+z^3)x^3+(y^4+4y^3z-8y^2z^2+4yz^3+z^4)x^2+$$
$$+2yz(y^3+y^2z+yz^2+z^3)x+y^2z^2(y^2+yz+z^2)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x=t\sqrt{yz}$ and since
$$y+z\geq2\sqrt{yz},$$
$$y^3-2y^2z-2yz^2+z^3\geq-2\sqrt{y^3z^3},$$
$$y^4+4y^3z-8y^2z^2+4yz^3+z^4\geq2y^2z^2,$$
$$2yz(y^3+y^2z+yz^2+z^3)\geq8\sqrt{y^5z^5}$$ and
$$y^2z^2(y^2+yz+z^2)\geq3y^3z^3,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$2t^5-t^4-6t^3+2t^2+8t+3\geq0$$ or
$$(t+1)^2(2t^3-5t^2+2t+3)\geq0,$$ which we proved already by AM-GM.

Done!

Comment: It's Nice,and I Love inequality,Dear Michael   I like inequality very much but there are some problems that I often encounter. Do you have Facebook for email to give me?It's easy to communicate.  I want to be your friend. Thank you.

Comment: @communnites I don't like social networks. You can ask me here or in the AoPS.